# Multiple HTTP POST request is not returning responses accordingly

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve hundreds(may be thousands in future) of http POST request's response here by iterating Database. I am not getting responses for a large number of requests but when i use this only for a few requests then i am getting responses perfectly. Can you Please explain how can i make sure of getting all responses? thanks in advance.

```
async function getDataFromDB(){
var allPromise = [];
var i = 0;

let d1 = new Date;
let utc1 = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
let myDate1 = new Date(utc + (3600000*(+6.0)));
myDate1 = myDate1.toString();
return ref.on('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        allPromise.push(callbackFunction(childSnapshot.key, childData['ReceiptData'], myDate1));
    });
    Promise.all(allPromise)
    .then((result) =>{
        for (i = 0; i < allPromise.length; i++) {
            parseData(ids[i], result[i], myDate1);
        }
        return result;
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log("promise error :"+err);
    });
    console.log("done");

  });
}
let callbackFunction = function(userID, receiptData, myDate){
console.log("from callback");
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        let password = 'my_password';
    const data = JSON.stringify({
            'receipt-data': receiptData,
            'password' : password,
            'exclude-old-transactions': false
        });
        const options = {
            resolveWithFullResponse: true,
            hostname: 'buy.itunes.apple.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/verifyReceipt',
            method: 'POST',
            json: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        };
        try{
            const req = https.request(options, res => {
            myStatusCode[0] = res.statusCode;
            var body = '';

            console.log(`statusCode : ${res.statusCode} : ${userID}`);
            res.on('data', d => {
                body = body + d;                
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log("body keys = " + body.keys);
                resolve(body);
            });
            res.on("error", err => {
                console.error("request error : "+err);
                reject(err);
            });
        });
        req.write(data);
        req.end();
        }catch(er){
            console.error("request error : "+ er);
        }
    });
  },1500);
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use Realtime Database's `on()` in Cloud Functions.  If you want to fetch data a single time, use `once()`, and make use of the promise it returns.

Comment: If your using node then node is single threaded, I don't think it's suitable for your application.

Comment: after using "once" instead of "on" solves the problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hammering too much and opening too many promises in parallel. COnsidering the number is going to increasein future, I would suggest to batch them and then send it over.

Something like this can help - https://www.npmjs.com/package/batch-promises

```
batchPromises(100, snapshot, childSnapshot => {
  const childData = childSnapshot.val();
  return callbackFunction(childSnapshot.key, childData.ReceiptData, myDate1);
})
```